# Unit testing axios.mockImplementation calls keeps giving me unchanged state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, axios

I'm still trying to learn unit testing and I've used a lot of guides, but for some reason in regards to axios testing, I'm messing up.

Note: I have "jest.mock("axios");" already set at the top of my testpage

```
getUserInfo = async () => {
  let authToken =
        "Bearer " + Cookies.get("auth-token").replace("__#__", ".");

    const instance = await axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
        timeout: 8000,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            Authorization: authToken
        }
    });

    instance
        .get("api/userinfo")
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                user: json.data
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserInfo();
}
```

and my testing is :

```
  it("fetches data correctly", async () => {  

    const userJSON = {
        data: {
            name: "John Doe",
            email: "johndoe@mail.com",
            phone_number: "123-456-7890",
            profile_url: "url"
        }
    };


    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ userJSON }));

    const instance = await renderer.create(<ProfilePage />).getInstance();
    expect(instance.state.user).toEqual(userJSON)}
```

and this is the output of the test which fails:

```
Expected: {"data": {"email": "johndoe@mail.com", "name": "John Doe", "phone_number": "123-456-7890", "profile_url": "url"}}
Received: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mostly because of the way you have written the `getUserInfo` method. While your idea of writing it as an `async-await` method is absolutely correct, you have put the await statement at the wrong place.

`axios.create` returns an axios instance that can be used to fire XHR requests. So,it does not require an await. You need to place the await with the `axios.get` call since that returns a promise. Because of this, your rendered component would not have resolved the value when you assert for the state update.

Also noticed that your assertion is incorrect. Since you are assigning the value of `json.data` to `state.users`, your expect will always fail.

So, the following change should do the trick for you:

Source Code:

```
getUserInfo = async () => {
    let authToken = 
        "Bearer " + Cookies.get("auth-token").replace("__#__", ".");

    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
        timeout: 8000,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            Authorization: authToken
        }
    });

    await instance
        .get("api/userinfo")
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                user: json.data
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserInfo();
}
```

Tests:

```
it("fetches data correctly", async () => {
    const userJSON = {
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "johndoe@mail.com",
        phone_number: "123-456-7890",
        profile_url: "url"
    };
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: userJSON });
    let instance = await renderer.create(<HomePage />).getInstance();
    expect(instance.state.user).toEqual(userJSON)
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. It worked as you said, I've been having problems with unit testing axios calls for whatever reason. Understanding how unit testing works for these axios calls has been frustrating. Thanks for the detailed explanation !

Comment: Happy to help! Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem